# Php/json: decode utf8?

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I store a json string that contains some (chinese ?) characters in a mysql database.
Example of what's in the database:

```
normal.text.\u8bf1\u60d1.rest.of.text
```

On my PHP page I just do a json_decode of what I receive from mysql, but it doesn't display right, it shows things like "½±è§�"

I've tried to execute the "SET NAMES 'utf8'" query at the beginning of my file, didn't change anything.
I already have the following header on my webpage:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

And of course all my php files are encoded in UTF-8.

Do you have any idea how to display these "\uXXXX" characters nicely?

Comment: Are these the characters that should be displayed: 诱惑 ?

Comment: Show us more of what exactly you're doing. `echo json_decode('"\u8bf1\u60d1"');` should do the trick perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode is not UTF-8!

```
$ echo -en '\x8b\xf1\x60\xd1\x00\n' | iconv -f unicodebig -t utf-8
诱惑
```

This is a strange "encoding" you have. I guess each character of the normal text is "one byte" long (US-ASCII)? Then you have to extract the \u.... sequences, convert the sequence in a "two byte" character and convert that character with `iconv("unicodebig", "utf-8", $character)` to an UTF-8 character (see [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) in the PHP-documentation). This worked on my side:

```
$in = "normal.text.\u8bf1\u60d1.rest.of.text";

function ewchar_to_utf8($matches) {
    $ewchar = $matches[1];
    $binwchar = hexdec($ewchar);
    $wchar = chr(($binwchar >> 8) & 0xFF) . chr(($binwchar) & 0xFF);
    return iconv("unicodebig", "utf-8", $wchar);
}

function special_unicode_to_utf8($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4})/i", "ewchar_to_utf8", $str);
}

echo special_unicode_to_utf8($in);
```

Otherwise we need more Information on how your string in the database is encoded.

Comment: The encoding is the result of `json_encode()` (or some other compatible encoder), `json_decode()` should be enough to convert it back.

Comment: @therefromhere: you are probably right, but shouldn't the JSON-encoder output valid Javascript? Because the quotes (") are missing its just text and not really JSON. A part from that, on my side `json_decode` also prints the correct result, just like in your answer.

Comment: Indeed, I assume the question example is a snippet of a larger properly formatted JSON string.

Comment: -1 for overcomplicated solution. `echo json_decode('"\u8bf1\u60d1"');` works perfectly fine. It's also not a "strange encoding", it's a perfectly fine Unicode code point encoding used in JSON.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work fine for me, with PHP 5.3.5 on Ubuntu 11.04:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"');
$json = '[ "normal.text.\u8bf1\u60d1.rest.of.text" ]';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($decoded);
```

Outputs this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "normal.text.诱惑.rest.of.text"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

That's a red herring. If you serve your page over http, and the response contains a `Content-Type` header, then the meta tag will be ignored. By default, PHP will set such a header, if you don't do it explicitly. And the default is set as `iso-8859-1`.

Try with this line:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. Also I have to mention that firefox says the page is in UTF8 so I guess the headers are already good ?