# Parsing unicode tweet text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, twitter, unicode

I'm not sure which part of my script is actually wrong, but I'm having some hard time with parsing tweet text with unicode characters in it:

Example tweet:

```
Landsliðsmaður með viti. #rafhlaða #hræddur http://t.co/ci03F3vUNM
```

When I fetch it with [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) and save it to .txt file, this string transforms to this in the file:

```
Landsli\u00f0sma\u00f0ur me\u00f0 viti. #rafhla\u00f0a #hr\u00e6ddur http:\/\/t.co\/ci03F3vUNM
```

I'm using simple `preg_replace`
 to replace text with hyperlinks

```
function twitterify($ret) {
  $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
  $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
  $ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $ret);
  $ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $ret);
  return $ret;
}
```

but this fails whenever it hits one of the unicode characters:
`#rafhlaða` becomes `<a href="#">#rafhla</a>ða`
`#hræddur` becomes `<a href="#">#hr</a>æddur`
and similar.

Which part am I doing wrong here? Saving/opening of my text file with PHP or parsing the unicode coded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here, I put the u modifier at the end of all your regexps, and it worked. Save the file as utf8. If you have json encoded string, you can decode it, using this solution: [Php/json: decode utf8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709593/php-json-decode-utf8)

```
<?php
function ewchar_to_utf8($matches) {
    $ewchar = $matches[1];
    $binwchar = hexdec($ewchar);
    $wchar = chr(($binwchar >> 8) & 0xFF) . chr(($binwchar) & 0xFF);
    return iconv("unicodebig", "utf-8", $wchar);
}

function special_unicode_to_utf8($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4})/i", "ewchar_to_utf8", $str);
}

$text = 'Landsli\u00f0sma\u00f0ur me\u00f0 viti. #rafhla\u00f0a #hr\u00e6ddur http:\/\/t.co\/ci03F3vUNM';
$text = special_unicode_to_utf8($text);

function twitterify($ret) {
  $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#u", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
  $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#u", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
  $ret = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/u", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $ret);
  $ret = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/u", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $ret);
  return $ret;
}

$text = twitterify($text);
print $text;
```

Prints:

`Landsliðsmaður með viti. <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=rafhlaða" target="_blank">#rafhlaða</a> <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=hræddur" target="_blank">#hræddur</a> http:\/\/t.co\/ci03F3vUNM`

Comment: Thanks for fixing the regex, however seems like I should escape unicode characters before saving to file, in `json_encode` function, which has this specific options for PHP v5.4+ which (of course) I cannot upgrade -.-

Comment: @errata I updated the answer, decoding the json encoded urf8. Plz, look. I am not sure only about escaping of slashes in http:\/\/

Comment: Thanks for all the effort! However, this still don't work, I suppose that's because I'm looping my array *after* I do `json_decode($tweets_file);`. Actually, if I do `var_dump($ret);` in `twitterify()` I don't see unicode characters anymore, but they are stored in text file.

Comment: @errata I don't know, what is your file contents and how do you read it. Plz, post the code, so I could reproduce the problem. But better try to reduce the problem as much as possible before posting here. Maybe, you'll be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: @errata Or better post it as a new question. I think, I gave you the answer in the scope of the current question.